# WFS-T with Geoserver and a Shapefile

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wfs-t

I have read that Geoserver fully supports **WFS-Transactions**. But for example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57692/geoserver-shapefile-or-postgis) somebody also mentioned that **shapefile-datastores** would not be the best choice for using Transactions in Geoserver, and that it would be better to do the transactions in a **database-store**, such as PostGIS.
Things may have changed over the years, so my question is:

Does Geoserver has **any limitations** in using **WFS-T with Shapefiles**?