# Failed to update feature through WFS with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, update, wfs-t

I am trying to update a polygon shapefile via a WFS service created using GeoServer. The client used for updating WFS is QGIS. So far I have been able to create a new feature successfully but I'm unable to update/delete an existing feature. Every time I try to update the existing feature, a new feature is created and the old feature is also retained. While deleting a feature does not work.

I am unable to figure the reason why.

Note: Editing of WFS has to be through QGIS

Comment: What version of QGIS / what version of Geoserver / what OS?
What kind of datasource for Geoserver?
What does QGIS log say? (View --> Panels --> Log Messages Panel)

Comment: QGIS version 2.14, Geoserver 2.9.0, OS- Windows Professional, Datasource- SHP (without database), No error log found in QGIS

Answer (score 3):

WFS-T and shape is a no:

> Shapefiles are a very common format for geospatial data. But if you
>   are running GeoServer in a production environment, it is better to use
>   a spatial database such as PostGIS. This is essential if doing
>   transactions (WFS-T). Most spatial databases provide shapefile
>   conversion tools. Although there are many options for spatial
>   databases (see the section on Working with Databases), PostGIS is
>   recommended. Oracle, DB2, and ArcSDE are also supported.

Source: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/data.html

Answer found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57693/63260